Problems with understanding Dirac Delta Properties
I need to check equation ${\bf 6.15}$ in an $\tt arxiv$ paper for my work, but I don't get why the Dirac Distributions change and why there is that exponential function with the derrivative.

I couldn't find any properties, that help get to that answer.

Can you help me ?.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
